# How else can I check the user for a program?

Tags: php, c++

Currently, my friend has a program that checks the users Windows CD-Key and then it goes  through a one way encryption. He, then, adds that new generated number to the program for checking purposes and then he compiles it and then he sends it off to the client. Is there a better way to keep the program from being shared utilizing PHP somehow instead of his current method while not using a login system of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, I've done extensive research in this area, a more affordable, and some say safer option to Zend Guard is [SourceGuardian](http://www.sourceguardian.com). It allows binding to IP addresses, MAC addresses, domains, and time. They're also working on a version that will support a physical dongle attached to the computer. They also release often and have pretty good support.

Another affordable and secure option is [NuCoder](http://www.nucoder.com), they have similar options to SourceGuardian, but also allow the option to bind to a uniquely generated hardware id.

Both SourceGuardian and NuCoder are the best out there, in my opinion anyway, however NuCoder has fallen behind in supporting the latest PHP releases. Currently they support up to 5.2, while SourceGuardian supports the very latest, including 5.3.

Furthermore, since your code is converted to protected bytecode, you also gain speed benefits as PHP doesn't need to take the extra step to convert your code into bytecode. However, as the previous commenter noted, this will require your users to install the necessary loaders, however, this usually entails a simple line addition to the php.ini, or in the case of > 5.2.6, otherwise no additions are usually necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In short, any program using a key can be forged one way or another. Especially if the sources are available (which is the case with most PHP projects. You might want to look into [Zend Gard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) if you really want something professional.) But most security systems are a pain to the clients in my opinion.

A *good* system I came across once was an C compiled library that had many redundant code checks (spaghetti-like calling trees) and would validate an encrypted serial number. Since the application was custom and did not have many releases, there was no "crack" available for it and the client was in deep water when the reseller went into bankruptcy. Eventually, that code was cracked anyway.

In my opinion, the only true secure way would be to host your application and not releasing any of your source code, then have the client pay for a license and send him only an API key that he must send for each request.